# Selenium VBA - Unable to open basic browser

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am just trying out selenium but I am getting errors even from basic tutorial scripts so I just wondered if there is something else I need to download. I have downloaded SeleniumBasic and enabled the Selenium reference library. The very basic test code I am using is this:

```
Sub test2()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim rowc, cc, columnC As Integer
rowc = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
driver.Start "chrome" ' debug points to this line
driver.Get "http://demo.guru99.com/test/web-table-element.php"
For Each th In driver.FindElementByClass("dataTable").FindElementByTag("thead").FindElementsByTag("tr")
cc = 1
For Each t In th.FindElementsByTag("th")
Sheet2.Cells(1, cc).Value = t.Text
cc = cc + 1
Next t
Next th
For Each tr In driver.FindElementByClass("dataTable").FindElementByTag("tbody").FindElementsByTag("tr")
columnC = 1
For Each td In tr.FindElementsByTag("td")
Sheet2.Cells(rowc, columnC).Value = td.Text
columnC = columnC + 1
Next td
rowc = rowc + 1
Next tr
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
End Sub
```

But I get this error message

[image: Error Selenium]

Comment: Yes thanks, first hour on selenium so wasn't expecting a bump like that in a tutorial